# Definition of a a component of a set

Tags: general-topology

What is the definition of a component of a set $A$ being a subset of a topological space? Is it the maximum (in the sense of inclusion) connected set included in $A$?

Comment: A _connected_ component is _a_ maximal connected subset of $A$. There are other kinds of component as well, though, so we need a bit more context to be able to give a full answer.

Comment: Yes, but you want "maximal" instead of "maximum".  A "maximum" means that there is only one.

Comment: Exactly, I want maximal.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite simple: A set $A$ in a topological space $X$ or a maximal connected set in $X$ if $A$ is connected and not a subset of any other connected set in $X$. Therefore if $A$ is a component and $B$ is a connected set such that $A\subseteq B$ then $A=B$. Distinct components are separate sets because if $A$ and $B$ are connected sets and if $A$ and $B$ are not separated, then we have $A\cup B$ is a connected set which contains $A$ and $B$ as proper subsets. This separation property implies that if $A$ and $B$ are components in $X$, then either $A=B$ or $A\cap B= \phi$. Each point $x$ of $X$ belongs to some component, namely to the union of all connected sets containing $x$. Hence the set of all components of a space $X$ determines an equivalence relation on $X$.

Comment: I feel that you are not answering the question.